# Shrink a DB and Log File in SQL after a database clear

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

We have a script that we use for client conversions that deletes all date from almost every table from a database.  We do this so that we can clear out any data not related to the application configuration, so that we can start to import data again (test conversions).

Would it be wise to shrink the DB after that process?
Will the continued cycle of import data-->delete data-->import data-->delete data cause fragmentation and "artificial growth" of the DB size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Log file shrinks are ok with runaway log files.  Data file shrinks, not so good.  To quote Paul Randal (former owner of the shrink code):

> "...data file shrink causes *massive*
>   index fragmentation."

Have a read through his post about [**shrinking log and data files**](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx).  Pretty much sums it up.